# (21,6) : error 0019: Each property name in a type must be unique.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Hi I know this has been asked quiet a few times, and though I read other users answers I still can't seem to figure it out, I'm getting this error after trying to initialize my database with EF code first:

(21,6) : error 0019: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'AlumnoID' was already defined.

here is my proyect structure: http://s17.postimg.org/u2jsvjke7/solutionexplorer.png

here is the configuration of the poco class that I'm getting the error:

```
   public class AlumnosConfiguracion : EntityTypeConfiguration<tblAlumnos>
    {
    public AlumnosConfiguracion()
    {
        this.HasKey(p => p.AlumnoID);
       // this.Property(p => p.AlumnoID).HasColumnOrder(0);


        this.Property(p => p.Matricula).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.ApellidoPaterno).HasMaxLength(120).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.ApellidoMaterno).HasMaxLength(120).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.Nombres).HasMaxLength(25).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.Edad).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.Sexo).HasMaxLength(10).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.FechaNacimiento).HasMaxLength(20).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.Nacionalidad).HasMaxLength(25).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.Telefono).HasMaxLength(25).IsOptional();
        this.Property(p => p.DomicilioID).IsOptional();
        this.Property(p => p.Activo).IsRequired();

        //Relacion direccion a alumnos, un alumno una direccion, una direccion muchos alumnos.
        this.HasRequired(a => a.objDomicilio)
            .WithMany(d => d.alumnos)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.DomicilioID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        //Relacion Plantel a alumnos, donde un planetel puede tener muchos alumnos, pero un alumno un plantel.
        this.HasRequired(a => a.objPlantel)
            .WithMany(p => p.alumnos)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.PlantelID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

here is db context class:

namespace GestionAlumnos.Contexto
{
    public class Alumnosdb : DbContext
    {
        //Constructor para que el nombre de la base de datos sea igual en sqlserver.
        public Alumnosdb() : base(nameOrConnectionString: Alumnosdb.ConnectionStringName){}

```
    //Static Constructor
    static Alumnosdb()
    {
        //here I initialize my database
        Database.SetInitializer(new AlumnosDbInicializador());
    }


    public DbSet<tblAlumnos> Alumnos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<tblUsuarios> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AlumnosSemestres> AlumnosSemestres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AnioPeriodo> AnioPeriodo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<tblColegios> Colegios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<tblDomicilios> Domicilios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<tblPeriodos> Periodos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<tblPlanteles> Planteles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<tblSemestres> Semestres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<tblTurnos> Turnos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<tblRoles> Roles { get; set; }


    public static string ConnectionStringName
    {
        get
        {                                       
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringName"] != null)
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringName"].ToString();
            }

            return "DefaultConnection";
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AlumnosConfiguracion());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AlumnosSemestresConfiguracion());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AnioPeriodoConfiguracion());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ColegiosConfiguracion());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DomiciliosConfiguracion());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PeriodosConfiguracion());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PlantelesConfiguracion());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RolesConfiguracion());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SemestresConfiguracion());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TurnosConfiguracion());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UsuariosConfiguracion());

        //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }


}
```

}

and this is the error I get after trying to initialize my dababase:

http://s12.postimg.org/q019oyo4d/error.png

I'm desperate I've been struggling with this for days now, If someone would like to take a look at my code let me know and I will send it to you, but please help with these, already tried with Julie Lerman said about deleting the left over assemblies but still no results, hopefully someone here would be able to help me.

Thanks for  your future suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution right here:

```
public class UsuariosConfiguracion : EntityTypeConfiguration<tblUsuarios>
     {
    public UsuariosConfiguracion()
    {
        //Relacion uno a uno. Un alumno un Usuarios.
        this.HasRequired(u => u.objAlumno)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(a => a.objUsuario);
            .Map(p => p.MapKey("AlumnoID")); // <<< Right HERE  
      }
   }
```

When I was trying to perform a one to one relationship with EF, I was mapping to an existing database so thats why EF was complaining saying that there was already an entity with a name of "AlumnoID" so what I did to solve it was getting rid of the mapping and just left it was fallows:

```
this.HasRequired(u => u.objAlumno)
.WithRequiredPrincipal(a => a.objUsuario);
```

And that solve the issue I had been struggling for the few past days, so incase if someone is having the same problem as I was, check your EF relationships first.

Thanks for reading this.